# DBMS_OUTPUT not working within procedure in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure, dbms-output

I am using Oracle and SQL Developer and I tried to code the function below. All is working fine, except for `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. My console for output was activated in SQL Developer. My query was OK, all field are OK. Did the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` work like this for a procedure?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_proc1 (pNoCmd number)
AS
vTotalCmd number;
BEGIN   
    SELECT s_ord.total INTO vTotalCmd FROM s_ord WHERE id = pNoCmd;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Le total de la commande ' || pNoCmd || ' est ' || vTotalCmd || '$');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Il n''y a pas de commande : ' || pNoCmd);
END;
/
CALL sp_proc1(97);
```

Anyone see error(s)?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: When I call my procedure with CALL, nothing print in my SGBD output in SQL developer

Comment: execute `set serveroutput on` first

Comment: You need to execute `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED` first

Comment: Ok this work fine for the first time. But if I want to CALL another number in my procedure, using CALL sp_proc1(144), nothing was show.. :o

Comment: I use EXEC instead of CALL and all work fine! :)